# Microsoft Azure Data Lake Storage

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I have a **Free trial Azure account**. While creating **Data Lake Store account** ,there is an option "**Pricing: Pay As You Go**". If i select "Pay As You Go" , it will charge me for this storage account??

Comment: yes, if you select "Pay As You Go", you will charge for this storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @JasonYe-MSFT said, and you can [see what you can do with Azure for free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/pricing-offers/), which list all of Azure free services that not includes Data Lake Store.